# options_from_collection_for_select issue in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating select group and trying to fetch data from database and populate same in select group.I need to populate groupname which is available in execution_group table. I am getting 'undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass' error.How to solve this issue? Below the code i am using.

```
<select id="select-execution-group" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select Group Name</option>
  <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@execution_group,:groupname, :groupname) %>
</select>
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: @execution_group isn't getting the results, are you sure that you are populating it?

Comment: I'd recommend you to do everything using rails helpers. You have `select_tag` and you can add the option `prompt: 'Select Group Name'`. What's in `@excecution_group`? Looks like it's nil.

Comment: Thanks I have made Mistake in routes Now working fine